# Return string as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to return a string result from a service, to be used in a pipe. I have an event, that I'd like to break up, and add a class if a team playing is favorited. Using Angular 8 btw

This is what I am trying:

```
     convertEventToString(event: SportEvent ) {
    let homeclass = 'hometeam';
    let awayclass = 'awayteam';
    return this.fetchTeam(event.idHomeTeam).pipe(
      mergeMap(team => {
        const t = team[0] as Team;
        if (t.favorite) {
          homeclass = 'favoriteteam';
        }
        return this.fetchTeam(event.idAwayTeam);
      })
    ).subscribe(team => {
      const t = team[0] as Team;
      if (t.favorite) {
        awayclass = 'favoriteteam';
      }
      const ret = `<span class="${homeclass}">${event.strHomeTeam}<span> vs <span class="${awayclass}">${event.strAwayTeam}`;
      return ret;
    });
   }
```

I've tried returning of(ret) in stead, but I guess I do not know how to return the observable, to use in an async pipe.

The FetchTeam method used in here gets a team from firestore

```
    fetchTeam(teamid: string) {
       return this.db
      .collection('teams', ref => ref.where('idTeam', '==', teamid))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do a ".subscribe", it converts the result to a subscription, instead of observable.

You can subscribe to your observable later, but here just .pipe(map) instead of .subscribe

```
convertEventToString(event: SportEvent ) {
  let homeclass = 'hometeam';
  let awayclass = 'awayteam';
  return this.fetchTeam(event.idHomeTeam).pipe(
    mergeMap(team => {
      const t = team[0] as Team;
      if (t.favorite) {
        homeclass = 'favoriteteam';
      }
      return this.fetchTeam(event.idAwayTeam);
    }),
    map(team => {
      const t = team[0] as Team;
      if (t.favorite) {
        awayclass = 'favoriteteam';
      }
      const ret = `<span class="${homeclass}">${event.strHomeTeam}<span> vs <span class="${awayclass}">${event.strAwayTeam}`;
      return ret;
    })
  );
}
```

P.S. don't forget to subscribe to your observable in the end, otherwise, it will not be performed.